# What elegant and Turing-complete machines* you know? Is there a one from The Book?

Tags: lambda-calculus, turing-complete

Lambda calculus of course is quite elegant, but doesn't it bother you that there is this asymmetry between input and output of a function? I.e. you can make the function take two parameters (by returning a function) but you can't make it return two values.
I don't think we could find it in [The Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it return a *function* whose evaluations return two values.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can return a compound structure. Just like a vector function which returns a vector, which has separate components in there.

BTW what does your header question have to do with the actual question you've asked?